# What does "redefining module" error in erlang mean?

Tags: erlang

I added the [mochijson2.erl](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/source/browse/trunk/src/mochijson2.erl) module to my ejabberd src directory but when I try to compile the code I get the following error:

```
 ./mochijson2.erl:8: redefining module
```

Where could this module be defined? I don't have it in my source.

Comment: Is `mochiweb` (the application) itself somewhere in your Erlang lookup path?  If so the system already  knows about mochijson2 and by importing the file into your project you're double-defining the module.

Comment: I guess it comes installed by default because I got it working without adding the module to my source. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your module has two `-module(...)` directives, which is not allowed. Check the source code of the module.

Comment: Yes, this is a compiler error. It even tells you on whih line the module redefined.